# Bokeh figure doesn't updates on dropdown.on_change

Tags: python, bokeh

I have some problem with updating Bokeh plot. It's simple piece of code, one figure with one curve and one dropdown, which can changes time period, 7,10 and 30 days. When i change dropdown value, nothing happens.
I already have gone through various articles, but i didn't find clear answer for me. 
Code example is presented below.
Thanks

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime


TIME_PERIOD = 30

def get_data(period):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=period)
    start = today - timedelta
    df = data.DataReader(name="BTC-USD", data_source="yahoo", start=start)
    dates = df.loc[str(start):str(today)].index
    y = df["Volume"]
    data1 = dict(
        xaxis=dates,
        yaxis=y
    )
    source = ColumnDataSource(data1)
    return source


def update_date(attr, old, new):
    global TIME_PERIOD
    temp = new
    TIME_PERIOD = int(temp)


def get_plot(data_source):
    p = figure(title="Cryptocurrencies volumes", x_axis_label="Дни", y_axis_label="Volume 24hr",
               x_axis_type="datetime")
    p.line(x="xaxis", y="yaxis", color="green", source=data_source)
    return p

dropdown_menu = [("7","7"),("10","10"),("30","30")]
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Выбор временного интервала",button_type="success",menu=dropdown_menu, value="30")
dropdown.on_change("value", update_date)

data1 = get_data(TIME_PERIOD)
plot = get_plot(data1)

image = row(dropdown,plot)

curdoc().add_root(image)
curdoc().title = "Plot"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting your time period is not enough. You have to call the `get_data()` function again and set the data of the `ColumnDataSource` it returns as the data of the `ColumnDataSource` that is used by your line glyph.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

TIME_PERIOD = 30

def get_data(period):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=period)
    start = today - timedelta
    df = data.DataReader(name="BTC-USD", data_source="yahoo", start=start)
    dates = df.loc[str(start):str(today)].index
    y = df["Volume"]
    data1 = dict(
        xaxis=dates,
        yaxis=y
    )
    source = ColumnDataSource(data1)
    return source


def update_date(attr, old, new):
    TIME_PERIOD = int(new)
    newdata = get_data(TIME_PERIOD)
    source.data = newdata.data

dropdown_menu = [("7","7"),("10","10"),("30","30")]
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Выбор временного интервала",button_type="success",menu=dropdown_menu, value="30")
dropdown.on_change("value", update_date)

source = get_data(TIME_PERIOD)
p = figure(title="Cryptocurrencies volumes", x_axis_label="Дни", y_axis_label="Volume 24hr",
           x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x="xaxis", y="yaxis", color="green", source=source)

image = row(dropdown,p)

curdoc().add_root(image)
curdoc().title = "Plot"
```